# Call function from within node event handler

Tags: node.js, typescript, events, electron

I'm using *icpRenderer* to send messages in an electron app from the renderer to the main process. Below is the handler that listens for the messages. I'd like to call another function from within that handler. How can I bind this?

```js
const onMessageReceived = (m: string) => {
  console.log(m);
};

ipcMain.on('my-custom-signal', (event, arg) => {
  this.onMessageReceived(arg);// how can I call this?
});
```

Comment: remove `this` - unlike languages such as Java `this.something()` is completely different to `something()`

Comment: this works, thank you

Answer (score 2):

`this` is not the same inside the handler.

You can do this:

```
let that = this;
const onMessageReceived = (m: string) => {
  console.log(m);
};

ipcMain.on('my-custom-signal', (event, arg) => {
  that.onMessageReceived(arg); // how can I call this?
});
```